# PHP MAILER, HOW TO INSERT HTML TABLE

Tags: php, html, phpmailer

I have PHP mailer script and I am trying to add HTML table into it but when I do the script stops working.

Here's the PHP mailer script

```
<?php
// Insert your email/web addresses and correct paths
$mailto = 'adil@*******.co.uk' ;
$from = "web@city.com" ;
$subject = "Query from ******* 2012";
$headers = "From: ******* Website";
$formurl = "http://*******.co.uk/citycoaches3/formmail.php" ;
$errorurl = "http://*******.co.uk/citycoaches3/error.php" ;
$thankyouurl = "http://*******.co.uk/citycoaches3/thankyou.php" ;

// Place Your Form info here...
$pickuppoint = ($_POST['pickuppoint']);
$destination = ($_POST['destination']);

// Check If Empty

// Add more Validation/Cleaning here...

// Place your Corresponding info here...
$message =

    "Pick Point: $pickuppoint\n\n" .
    "Destination: $destination\n\n" . 
    "noppl: $noppl\n\n" 
;

// Leave Alone
mail($mailto, $from, $message);
header( "Location: $thankyouurl" );
exit ;

?>
```

Any help on this will be appreciated.

Heres what i tried

```
<?php

$fromAddr = 'adil@********.co.uk'; // the address to show in From field.
$recipientAddr = 'quotes@********.co.uk';
$subjectStr = '[Quick] Query From ********';
$date = date ("l, F jS, Y"); 
$time = date ("h:i A"); 
$forward = 1;
$formurl = "http://www.********.co.uk/formmail.php" ;
$errorurl = "http://www.********.co.uk/error.php" ;
$thankyouurl = "http://www.********.co.uk/thankyou.php" ;
header("location:thankyou.php");

$mailBodyText = <<<HHHHHHHHHHHHHH
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
<title>Thank You</title>
</head>
<body>
<img src="http://********.co.uk/images/mailsig.png" /> \n\n<br />
<span style="color:#900; font-size:18px;">Below is the result submitted from <strong>[Quick Quote] ******** Website</strong>. It was submitted on <strong>$date at $time</strong>.\n\n</span> 
<p><table width="600" border="1" cellpadding="5px">
  <tr>
    <td><b>Pickup Date:</b> </td>
    <td>{$_POST['date']}<br></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><b>Pickup Time:</b> </td>
    <td>{$_POST['PickupTime-Hours']}:{$_POST['PickupTime-Mins']}<br></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><b>Pickup Point:</b> </td>
    <td>{$_POST['PickUp-Point']}<br></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><b>Destination:</b> </td>
    <td>{$_POST['Destination']}<br></td></tr>
  <tr>
    <td><b>No. Of People:</b> </td>
    <td>{$_POST['No-of-Persons']}<br></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><b>Journey Type:</b> </td>
    <td>{$_POST['JourneyType']}<br></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <tr>
    <td><b>Return Date:</b> </td>
    <td>{$_POST['returnDate']}<br></td>
  </tr>
      <tr>
    <td><b>Return Time:</b> </td>
    <td>{$_POST['returnTime-Hours']}{$_POST['returnTime-Mins']}<br></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <tr>
    <td><b>Vehicle Type:</b> </td>
    <td>{$_POST['type']}<br></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <tr>
    <td><b>Full Name:</b> </td>
    <td>{$_POST['Full-Name']}<br></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <tr>
    <td><b>Tel / Mobile:</b> </td>
    <td>{$_POST['Tel-Mobile']}<br></td>
  </tr>
      <tr>
    <td><b>Email:</b> </td>
    <td>{$_POST['Email']}<br></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
</table>




</p>
</body>
</html>
HHHHHHHHHHHHHH;

$headers= <<<TTTTTTTTTTTT
From: $fromAddr
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/html;
TTTTTTTTTTTT;

mail($mailto, $from, $message,
    "From: \"$name\" <$email>" . $headersep . "Reply-To: \"$name\" <$email>" . $headersep );
header( "Location: $thankyouurl" );
exit ;

?>
```

Still doesn't work for some reason.

**Heres the UPDATE:**

After removing

```
"From: \"$name\" <$email>" . $headersep . "Reply-To: \"$name\" <$email>" .
```

I managed to receive the email, but it pasted the whole code which is in $message.

Comment: Show the code WITH the table as you've tried it, please.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to send mixed txt/html mails with the php mail function?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3675605/is-it-possible-to-send-mixed-txt-html-mails-with-the-php-mail-function)

Comment: Heres the example I tried but doesn't seems to work

Answer (score 0):

Try getting the HTML from a file :

```
$message =  file_get_contents('./path/email.html') // it's easyer to maintain but not mandatory
```

And add a html content type header

```
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
```

then

```
mail($mailto, $from, $message, $headers) //notice the headers;
```

Answer (score 0):

As I think the others answers didn't gave you the correct direction yet, here's my addition:

```
$name = _("test"); // Or insert variable

$message = <<<EOF

    // html here
    <p>hello $name</p>

EOF;

$to  = "";

$subject = "";

// To send HTML mail, the Content-type header must be set
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";

// Additional headers
$headers .= 'From: Example <info@example.com>' . "\r\n";

// Mail it
mail($to, $subject, $email, $headers);
```

You'll need the html headers when sending the email..

Answer (score 0):

ALL thank you very much for your help and suggestions.

I finally got it working here is what I did.

In $message in inserted:

```
$message = "<html><body>
<b><FONT COLOR='#900' SIZE='13px'>Hi this is working now</FONT></b>
<table width='400' border='0' cellpadding='5px'>
<tr>
    <td><b><FONT COLOR='#900'>Pickup Date:</FONT></b> </td>
    <td>{$_POST['date']}<br></td>
  </tr>
</table>
</html></body>";
```

And added following headers

```
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
```

All working thanks everyone again!

Answer (score -1):

Use [php html email](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) and insert table in email body part

Comment: I have used PHP HTML emailer in past, but I am using http://www.websitecodetutorials.com/code/jquery-plugins/jquery-ajaxsubmit.php tutorial from here. When I insert HTML tags in $message the script stops working.

Comment: ok, so initially question was not complete. Are you getting any error?Try error_reporting(E_ALL) and display errors on if you are getting blank page instead of error

Comment: My apologies for not providing all information at start. I have updated the question its sending the email after removing few headers but it is posting the whole code in email

Comment: It means there is problem in headers, It's getting text not html in header of email. You used $headers for defining html email but in mail function, I can't find $headers. You used $headersep not $headers. Plz check it.

Comment: Checked all the headers and changed the $headersep to $headers. Still doesn't work

Answer (score -1):

If you want to display the messagebody in your message to your recipient, maybe you should try putting a quotation mark in your code:

```
$mailBodyText = "<<<HHHHHHHHHHHHHH
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
<title>Thank You</title>
</head>
<body>
<img src="http://********.co.uk/images/mailsig.png" /> \n\n<br />
<span style="color:#900; font-size:18px;">Below is the result submitted from <strong>      [Quick Quote] ******** Website</strong>. It was submitted on <strong>$date at     $time</strong>.\n\n</span> 
<p><table width="600" border="1" cellpadding="5px">
 <tr>
 <td><b>Pickup Date:</b> </td>
 <td>{$_POST['date']}<br></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td><b>Pickup Time:</b> </td>
 <td>{$_POST['PickupTime-Hours']}:{$_POST['PickupTime-Mins']}<br></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td><b>Pickup Point:</b> </td>
 <td>{$_POST['PickUp-Point']}<br></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td><b>Destination:</b> </td>
   <td>{$_POST['Destination']}<br></td></tr>
  <tr>
   <td><b>No. Of People:</b> </td>
   <td>{$_POST['No-of-Persons']}<br></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
 <td><b>Journey Type:</b> </td>
 <td>{$_POST['JourneyType']}<br></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
   <tr>
   <td><b>Return Date:</b> </td>
    <td>{$_POST['returnDate']}<br></td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
  <td><b>Return Time:</b> </td>
   <td>{$_POST['returnTime-Hours']}{$_POST['returnTime-Mins']}<br></td>
 </tr>
 <tr> 
 <tr>
 <td><b>Vehicle Type:</b> </td>
 <td>{$_POST['type']}<br></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
   <tr>
  <td><b>Full Name:</b> </td>
  <td>{$_POST['Full-Name']}<br></td>
 </tr>
<tr>
  <tr>
 <td><b>Tel / Mobile:</b> </td>
  <td>{$_POST['Tel-Mobile']}<br></td>
</tr>
   <tr>
  <td><b>Email:</b> </td>
 <td>{$_POST['Email']}<br></td>
</tr>
 <tr>
</table>";
```

Comment: please change the double quote into single quote inside the double quote :)

Comment: Please check your code again, you're going in a total wrong direction... Using <<<* is better when inserting html inside a php variable.